# Can I delete the Styles_idx.dat file? in appdata/roaming?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Can I delete the *styles_idx.dat* file (in appdata/roaming - windows computer) - it is 125MB and causing trouble for my profile at the university, keeps saying my profile is full.

I have found the file, but did not want to delete it, if it would destroy my project?

Can I just shut the ArcMap program down, then delete the file and start up again?

What does this file actually represent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can delete it. It is the index file for the symbology, created when you search for a symbol. It would just be recreated at the next search.

This issue (placing a large file in the roaming profile, which is often restricted in size) is known to Esri but they have not yet addressed it.

See https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63346 (answer posted by me following past discussions with Esri UK support)